# Driving a Delta Load with a Wye

Tags: ac

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgcUOv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is it OK to drive a Delta Load with a Wye Source?  In my case the scenario is that I have a heater that has three resistances in a Delta Configuration.  However, our service entrance to the plant is a Wye.  Let's say it is possible(?) is there any downside to doing this?  Finally, the Delta Load is "isolated/floating" in a metal housing ( the heater enclosure ), should the Neutral wire from the Wye be tied to the metal case of the heater enclosure?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's going on at the end there?...

Comment: Don't try to make an ASCII diagram.  Instead, use the schematic editor; hit the Schematic button on the editor box top ribbon

Comment: And if you ever need to insert code or ASCII art, the whole block of it needs to be indented with 4 spaces.  Read the formatting help, it should explain all of it.  // But in this case, you should use the schematic editor instead.

Comment: Thanks to all!  This is the first time I have used Stack Exchange.  I used the schematic editor as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem when connecting a Delta configured load to a Wye source. 
In that case you do not connect the neutral wire. The wire to be connected to the metal case of the heater should be your earth connection. Somewhere down the line the earth and neutral come together again. That however is not visible here.

Beware of the voltages the delta load voltages. The voltage measured across the lines must be the same. Therefore not the WYe voltages against the neutral.

The information at the end of your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the line-to-line voltage of the source matches the terminal voltage requirement, there is no problem. There is no downside. The outside housing of the equipment should be connected to an equipment grounding conductor that is connected to an earth ground at or near the building electrical service entrance. The neutral is likely connected to ground near the service entrance also, but no equipment terminals should be connected to neutral unless the equipment uses the line-to-neutral voltage for a single-phase load.